# Cannot change mysql server collation with my.cnf

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

I want to change my MySQL server charset and collation from latin1 to UTF8. I researched a bit and it seems that this is done via "my.cnf" file which needs to be in a folder from which MySQL reads configuration options that you put in. I didn't have a "my.cnf file" on my Mac (OSX Yosemite, MySQL 5.7) so as per instructions I copied the example one to '/etc'.

Inside, I created entries for mysql-client, mysqld and mysql-server like so:

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# ...some stuff ...

[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

However, this doesn't work.

My settings show up as following:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | latin1             |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | latin1             |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database       | latin1_swedish_ci  |
| collation_server         | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What can I do to change it? Or should I just leave it as it is and set it at the db level when creating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, keep in mind that what you put into `my.cnf` is *defaults* and will *not* change any the table definitions for existing tables, nor any characters already stored in those tables.

The defaults for 'database' need to be under `[mysqld]`.

I ignore database defaults and simply be explicit whenever creating a table:

```
CREATE TABLE (...) ...
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    DEFAULT COLLATE       utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

That way, I cannot be burned by the kind of mis-configuration you describe.

You can also do

```
CREATE DATABASE ...
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    DEFAULT COLLATE       utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

Comment: Update:  8.0 has a way of persisting configuration changes made with `SET`.